# Determine name of last subfolder in a path (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby. I'm trying to figure out how to grab the name of a folder. I have this:

```
path = Dir["#{some_base_path}/*/*"]
```

Which gives me something like this:

`path: ["/tmp/animals/cats/Fluffy"]`

What I want is to know the name of the last subfolder - in this case `Fluffy`.

I've tried variations of `Pathname` and `File.basename`, but I always run into `no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)` errors.

What would be the best way to do this?`

Comment: Well, you have an array of strings. You want to apply `File.basename` et al to _elements_ of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: For example, not sure how suitable it is for your usecase, but one thing you could do is `path = Dir["#{some_base_path}/*/*"].first`

Comment: What if there are more than one such folders?

Comment: @mechnicov That shouldn't matter.  The idea here is to get the characters to the right of the last "/".  This person could simply tokenize, move that into a function and run a loop on the array.  It all depends on what the OP wants to do with the subfolder..

Answer (score 1):

You already have your path.  There is this neat thing in programming languages called [Tokenization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tokenization-1.html#:%7E:text=Given%20a%20character%20sequence%20and%20a%20defined%20document%20unit%2C%20tokenization%20is%20the%20task%20of%20chopping%20it%20up%20into%20pieces%2C%20called%20tokens%20%2C%20perhaps%20at%20the%20same%20time%20throwing%20away%20certain%20characters%2C%20such%20as%20punctuation)

You can split a string via a single character or more.

Starting with your array

```
paths = ["/tmp/animals/cats/Fluffy"]
=> ["/tmp/animals/cats/Fluffy"]
```

You could take the first element (which is your path string)

```
path = paths.first
=> "/tmp/animals/cats/Fluffy"
```

and [tokenize it with ruby](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-way/0768667208/0768667208_ch02lev1sec8.html)

```
tokens = path.split("/")
=> ["", "tmp", "animals", "cats", "Fluffy"]
```

and then return the last element of the array of "tokens".

```
tokens.last
=> "Fluffy"
```

Comment: Alternatively: `path.rpartition('/').last`

Comment: Yeah that's much cleaner for this case.  Though I think Tokenization is an important fundamental and applies in many cases and in many languages. It's less clean, but more basic.  And the OP is a beginner.

Comment: This will not work for operating systems where the path separation character is not `/`. Ruby is an object-oriented language, not a string-oriented language. Operations on pathnames should be performed on pathname objects, not string objects. (Granted, `Dir::[]` also shouldn't be returning strings, but just because the core library authors are doing it wrong doesn't mean you have to!)

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's true, that would be a more scalable way to implement this.  It is the technical solution, but is it practical?  You don't need Rocket Science and perfection to get the job done.  If you're planning on utilizing this so that multiple OS' can use it, you're gonna go with a more complex solution, but only do that if you need it.  For example, a bigger application that deals with a lot of uploading files from users might require this development style.  Whereas writing a script on your macbook to deploy code to that site might not need to be so strict in its path delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# Get array of subdirectories arrays
directories =
  Dir[pattern].
    filter_map { |filename| filename.split("/") if File.directory?(filename) }

# Get maximum subdirectories depth
max_depth = directories.max_by(&:size).size

# Get all subdirectories (tree leaves) with maximum depth
directories.filter_map { |dirs| dirs.last if dirs.size == max_depth }
```